# How to convert the string 11-07-1995 to Friday 7 1995?? Android

Tags: java, android, date

I can convert the string to date, but when I want to convert the string in other type of data it is wrong.

```
String string = "1995 11 07";
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("cccc F MMMM yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
date = fmt.parse(string);
Toast.makeText(getContext(), date.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

What is the correct practice?

Comment: You're specifying your desired *output* format as your *parsing* format. You need two `SimpleDateFormat` objects - one with your input format, to parse, and then one with your output format, to format...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion/

Comment: Please search and study Stack Overflow before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String input_date="01/08/2012";
SimpleDateFormat format1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date dt1=format1.parse(input_date);
DateFormat format2=new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE"); 
String finalDay=format2.format(dt1)
```